# how to run the functions inside the slidable actions onpressed

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I have a slidable in my code and i want to run the functions inside each card on pressed when run it it runs with the loop and after that the onpressed like its not pressed(null) how can the functions runs with the onpressed??

```dart
// A SlidableAction can have an icon and/or a label.
              SlidableAction(
                onPressed: deletTransact(),
                backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFE4A49),
                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                icon: Icons.delete,

                label: 'Delete',
              ),


  SlidableAction(
                // An action can be bigger than the others.
                flex: 2,
                onPressed: editTransact(),
                backgroundColor: Color(0xFF2196f3),
                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                icon: Icons.edit,
                label: 'Edit',
              ),


deletTransact() {
  print("delete");


  }

  editTransact() {    print("edit");


  }
}
```

Comment: which package you are using?

Comment: flutter_slidable: ^1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

```
                           SlidableAction(
                              flex: 2,
                              onPressed: (BuildContextcontext){
                                    //RUN your code 
                              }
                              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                              foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                              icon: Icons.delete,
                              label: 'Remove',
                            ),
```